# MySQL Left Join + Min

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, greatest-n-per-group, min

Seemingly simple MySQL question, but I've never had to do this before..

I have two tables, items and prices, with a one-to-many relationship.

```
Items Table
id, name

Prices Table
id, item_id, price
```

Where

```
prices.item_id = items.id
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT items.id, items.name, MIN(prices.price)
FROM items
LEFT JOIN prices ON items.id = prices.item_id
GROUP BY items.id
```

How do I also return the corresponding prices.id for that minimum price? Thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will return multiple records for a record in Items if there are multiple Prices records for it with the minimum price:

```
select items.id, items.name, prices.price, prices.id
from items
left join prices on (
    items.id = prices.item_id 
    and prices.price = (
        select min(price)
        from prices
        where item_id = items.id
    )
);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I was getting closer to coming up with this... knew I would need a subquery somewhere.

Comment: This is the query I was working on to replace my answer, but Patrick beat me to it.

Comment: How is this for efficiency as implemented a similar query and its killed my load time, even with various indexes etc

Comment: Seems to work, but I have the same problem like @Horse The load time is not acceptable and is not production ready in my  case.

Answer (score 17):

New, working answer, based on the final example in the MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual - [3.6.4. The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT items.id, items.name, prices.price, prices.id
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN prices
    ON prices.item_id = items.id
LEFT JOIN prices AS filter
    ON filter.item_id = prices.item_id
    AND filter.price < prices.price
WHERE filter.id IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` works on the basis that when `prices.price` is at its minimum value, there is no `filter.price` with a smaller value and the `filter` rows values will be NULL.

---

Original incorrect answer:

```
SELECT items.id, items.name, prices.price, prices.id
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.item_id = items.id
ORDER BY prices.price ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm trying to display all results in the Items table. The LIMIT 1 here is applied to the main Items query and only returns one result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about?

```
SELECT items.id, items.name, MIN(prices.price), prices.id
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN prices ON items.id = prices.item_id 
GROUP BY items.id, MIN(prices.price)
```

Comment: When I do that, it returns the first prices.id that it finds, not the one that corresponds to the Minimum one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 items.id, items.name, prices.price, prices.id 
FROM items  
LEFT JOIN prices ON items.id = prices.item_id  
ORDER BY prices.price ASC
```