# Assign product category by string match from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lots of products that we need to assign categories and a table, that contains keywords by which you can identify what goes where.
There may be multiple keywords for one category, in this case the first match from top should be used.

I came up with this test case, which works as I need:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
    (`name` varchar(30), `category_id` int, `filter` varchar (30))
;

INSERT INTO Products
    (`name`)
VALUES
    ('Plate'),
    ('Mushrooms'),
    ('Mushroom soup in a plate'),
    ('Mushroom on a plate'),
    ('Tomato soup'),
    ('Sausage'),
    ('Soupcan')
;

CREATE TABLE Filters
(`filter` varchar(30), `category_name` varchar(30))
;
INSERT INTO Filters
    (`filter`, `category_name`)
VALUES
('Soup', 'Meals'),
('Mushroom', 'Ingredients'),
('Plate', 'Containers')
;

CREATE TABLE Categories
(`id` int, `name` varchar(30))
;
INSERT INTO Categories
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, "Ingredients"),
    (2, 'Containers'),
    (3, 'Meals')
;

update Products
left join Filters
on Products.name LIKE CONCAT('%',Filters.filter,'%')
join Categories
on Filters.category_name = Categories.name
set Products.category_id = Categories.id, Products.filter = Filters.filter;

select Products.*, Categories.name as category_name from Products
left join Categories on Products.category_id = Categories.id
```

Category gets assigned by first match in "filters", just as I need.
**But** if I add another row to Filter table that has same category_id (for example try adding: ('Soupcan', 'Containers') to Filters), the results will not be the first match (or the last).
"Mushroom soup in a plate" must go to "Meals", because it matches first filter row "Soup".
But if I add 'Soupcan', 'Containers' row to Filters - "Mushroom soup in a plate" will now match "Mushroom" and get into "Ingredients" category.
I think the problem lies in sorting between first and second join, but I can't figure it out.

If you know a better approach to this task - feel free to offer.
I just need to sort products by keyword matching, where topmost keyword matched will have the priority.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/436c63/1)

Comment: WHICH DBMS??????  SQL is a language.  It's useless if we post solution to the wrong dbms.  Below is a reference to SQL Server.  Is that useful for you?

Comment: @Eric Oops. Added tag for DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of SQL you are using.
But what you are looking for is a join of a subselect of the Filter table.

See these links for more info:

[SQL Server: How to Join to first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row)

[LEFT JOIN only first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626493/left-join-only-first-row)

Comment: Seems like it. I'll try it tomorrow and tell you how it went.

Comment: Coudn't get it to work with my case :( Getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" and no idea how to implement it correctly.

Comment: "GROUP BY Products.name;" gives me the desired result, but it only works after "select" for me, and not after "update", between two "left join" (MySQL 5.6).
I guess I better simplify\refine my question and post it again.

Comment: Created more general question and example, because I can't get anything working using your suggestions :(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142215/mysql-update-rows-with-double-left-join-limiting-first-match