# MySQL Update rows with double left join, limiting first match

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-update, left-join, mariadb

I have three tables ([SQLFiddle with tables created](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3dab))

[image]

Orange text is what I need to get by comparing Products.name with Filters.filter.

I figured out that substring match can be done like this:

```
on Products.name LIKE CONCAT('%',Filters.filter,'%');
```

I only need the first filter match to be used. So "Mushroom soup" will match "Soup" and not "Mushroom".

What is best approach for this task?

A tested SQLFiddle link, if possible, please.

What I tried: (*feel free to skip everything below*)

Tried double join:

```
update Products
left join Filters on Products.name LIKE CONCAT('%',Filters.filter,'%')
join Categories on Filters.category_name = Categories.name
set Products.category_id = Categories.id, Products.filter = Filters.filter;
```

But this doesn't result in **first** match being used, because first join returned **all** filter matches (multiple lines per 1 product), and after second join categories are from last match.

For example: Mushroom soup got into "Mushroom-Ingredients" filter\category, instead of "Soup\Meals".

Also tried join + order by:

```
select Products.name, Filters.* 
from Products
left join Filters on Products.name LIKE CONCAT('%',Filters.filter,'%')
group by Products.name;
```

This returns the first match per product as I needed, but I can't do a second left-join in the same query, neither can I get "group by" to work after "update" function instead of "select".

For when sqlfiddle collapses:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    `name` varchar(30), 
    `category_name` varchar (30), 
    `category_id` int
);

INSERT INTO Products (`name`)
VALUES ('Mushrooms'), ('Can of mushrooms'),
       ('Can of soup'), ('Mushroom soup'),
       ('Tomato soup'), ('Tomato');

CREATE TABLE Filters
(
     `filter` varchar(30), 
     `category_name` varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO Filters (`filter`, `category_name`)
VALUES ('Can of', 'Canned food'), ('Soup', 'Meals'),
       ('Mushroom', 'Ingredients'), ('Tomato', 'Ingredients');

CREATE TABLE Categories
(
     `id` int, 
     `name` varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO Categories (`id`, `name`)
VALUES (1, "Canned food"), (2, 'Ingredients'), (3, 'Meals');
```

Comment: Wow so nice to actually see such effort towards a [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy Thanks! Creating simple problem sample benefits everyone: the one who's having trouble, those who could help and those who will read this question in the future. Also, I often solve the problem before even posting here just by trying to create a simple test case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the task quite easy with your sqlfiddle as well as your attempt to solve the problem with Select query.

It works the way you want I guess and all I need to do is to add one more left join with category table (IDK why you were unable to join Category as it's working properly).

So. I've edited your select query as follows:

```
select Products.name, Filters.*,Categories.id from Products
left join Filters
on Products.name LIKE CONCAT('%',Filters.filter,'%')
left join Categories
on Categories.name = Filters.category_name
GROUP BY Products.name;
```

You will get the results you want with this query.

Now, in order to update `Products` table with the result of this query, you can do following:

```
update Products
left join Filters
on Products.name LIKE CONCAT('%',Filters.filter,'%')
left join Categories
on Categories.name = Filters.category_name
set Products.category_name = Filters.category_name, 
    Products.category_id = Categories.id;
```

[Click here for Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd929/1/0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Look at the result you've got in the last table: Tomato soup gets filter "Tomato" and category "Ingredients".
That's my problem: I need it to match the first row in "Filters" table.
For "Tomato soup" it will be "Soup", not "Tomato". Same goes for "Mushroom soup" - soup should have a higher match priority than "mushroom" or "tomato", because it comes first in "Filters" table.

Comment: Ok. I think I got the solution. Will update after a while as I am traveling rn.

Comment: UPD: The pevious comment is regarding the select you wrote on lines 7-12.  The update query seems to be working as I need, though. I guess I just wasted a few hours because I didn't write "left" before the second join. I also assumed "join" defaults to "join left" for some reason.  
Thanks for the help! I started digging in the wrong direction and needed a fresh look.  
And yes, I try my best to make the problem examples as accessible as possible, so that people have easy time helping me.