# Yii2, how to add a LIMIT on a leftjoin to get only 1 result back

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I am trying to get all records from the product table, these records are unique but i use a leftjoin to add a second table with images of these products but when I do it will return some products more than once as some products have 1 or more images. How can I use a limit on the product_images table to make sure it will just get 1 image instead of all. The example below does not work so is this possible?

```
$query->select( ['a.id', 'b.image as category_image' , 'c.image as product_image'] )
        ->from( ['a' => 'product'] )
        ->leftJoin( ['b' => 'product_images'] ,'a.id = b.id AND b.type = "category" AND LIMIT = 1')
        ->leftJoin( ['c' => 'product_images'] ,'a.id = c.id AND b.type = "product" AND LIMIT = 1')
        ->all();
```

Comment: did you try inner join?

Comment: yes i have tried this, but still multiple results.

Comment: actually try to remove AND before LIMIT, cause its not correct syntax

Comment: Tried that and this will return an error:  Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 1 LEFT JOIN

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626493/left-join-only-first-row or use inner select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by sub queries:

```
    $query->select(['a.id', 'b.image as category_image' , 'c.image as product_image'])
        ->from(['a' => 'product'])
        ->leftJoin(['b' => 'product_images'],
            'a.id = b.product_id AND b.id = (
                select id from product_images where product_id = a.id AND type = "category" order by id limit 1)')
        ->leftJoin(['c' => 'product_images'],                        
            'a.id = c.product_id AND c.id = (
                select id from product_images where product_id = a.id AND type = "product" order by id limit 1)')
        ->all();
```

You have to use composit indexes on the table `product_images` to have goood performance.

You could use other sorting as `order by id`, e.g. you could introduce an ordering field in the table `product_images`.

I think `a.id = b.id` and `a.id = c.id` was a simple mistake. It's about `a.id = b.product_id` and `a.id = c.product_id`.

Comment: This may be extremely inefficient for large datasets. Probably adding `GROUP BY` by product ID may give the same result but with much better performance.