# return the value with the highest ID, of a predetermined set of IDs in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, groupwise-maximum

I am attempting to pull the value associated with the highest detailID of a set of detailIDs that are predefined for each patientID.

here is an example of the table (also available as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c8ca63f65d543be661c083a6aeda85f)):

```
CREATE TABLE `patient_details` (
    patientId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    detailId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `value` VARCHAR(256),
    PRIMARY KEY (patientId, detailId),
    UNIQUE INDEX details_of_patient (patientId, detailId)
);

INSERT INTO patient_details (patientId, detailId, `value`)
  VALUES
(123, 75, '01'),
(123, 98, '02'),
(123, 151, '03 hit'),
(123, 251, '04'),

(321, 65, '05'),
(321, 75, '04'),
(321, 98, '03'),
(321, 151, '02 hit'),
(321, 180, '01'),

(123456, 75, '01'),
(123456, 89, '12/01/2022'),
(123456, 151, '03 hit'),
(123456, 215, '5681'),

(678910, 75, '01'),
(678910, 151, '03'),
(678910, 203, '12/01/2022 hit'),
(678910, 215, '56813')
;
```

What I need to do is pull the value of the highest detailID of 75, 151, 203.

I have tried using if function, to test the detailID but get syntax errors.

logically I am thinking I ought to be able to do something like this nested IF

```
select 
patientId,
table.value

if(detailid=203,set @largest_detailID=203,if(detailid=151,set @largest_detailID=151,if(detailid=75,set @largest_detailID=75,)))

from table

where detailID=@largest_detailID
```

What I would expect as a result

| patientID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 03 hit |
| 321 | 02 hit |
| 123456 | 03 hit |
| 678910 | 12/01/2022 hit |

While there are a number of questions and answers on this site addressing getting non-aggregate columns from rows corresponding to a maximum or minimum value (such as "[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1313120/18924757)", "[MySQL Left Join + Min](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7588142/18924757)"), they don't select from a limited list of values, nor is it trivial to adapt the answers to add this restriction.

Comment: WHERE is applied before SELECT

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: You should not be doing any numeric comparisons of the value of an ID column. Are you using "highest detailid" to mean "most recent record"? If so, then add a timestamp to each row, and find the highest timestamp.

Comment: Outis, thanks for the information I will do my best to remember that for next time, thank you for adding the additional info into my  post.

Comment: Andy, thanks for the information, I am reading an existing table, I do not recall there being a time stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to mess with all the `IF`'s and `@` variables, why not use a descending order of the `detailID` to help instead, and then add a `LIMIT 1` to get only the highest reference that exists based on the 3 `detailID` numbers from your criteria:

Try with:

```
SELECT patientId, value
  FROM patientInfo
 WHERE detailID IN (75, 151, 203)
 ORDER BY detailID DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

... and since a `detailID` of `203` and `89` does not exist in the query results will get the expected entry:

[image]

Example [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94fbbc9648cb9047724218cce4997e88).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to apply this logic across multiple patients, try using ROW_NUMBER() to partition the data by patientId then sort based on the highest detailId:

> ```
> WITH cte AS (
>     SELECT * 
>            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
>                  PARTITION BY PatientId 
>                  ORDER BY DetailID DESC
>             ) AS RowNum
>     FROM   YourTable
>     WHERE  DetailId IN (75, 151, 203)
> )
> SELECT * 
> FROM   cte 
> WHERE  RowNum = 1
> ```

**Sample Data:**

| patientId | detailId | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 75 | 01 |
| 123456 | 89 | 12/01/2022 |
| 123456 | 151 | 03 |
| 123456 | 215 | 56813 |
| 678910 | 75 | 01 |
| 678910 | 203 | 12/01/2022 |
| 678910 | 151 | 03 |
| 678910 | 215 | 56813 |

**Results:**

| patientId | detailId | value | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 151 | 03 | 1 |
| 678910 | 203 | 12/01/2022 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b53e975d682a638c1e9f29e03b97b256)*

Answer (score 0):

Queries for [group-wise maximums and minimums](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) provide a good starting point; the tricky part can be figuring out how to efficiently integrate the restriction on IDs.

### Correlated Subquery

[A correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) is easy to adapt, but can be poor in performance. Without the restriction, the first example in the MySQL manual can be converted by a simple change of names:

```
SELECT patientId, detailId, `value`
FROM   patient_details AS pd
WHERE  detailId=(
           SELECT MAX(pd2.detailId)
             FROM patient_details AS pd2
             WHERE pd.patientId = pd2.patientId
       )
;
```

Since the sub-query is the simple maximum from the results, adding a condition to the `WHERE` clause will restrict the `detailId`s appropriately:

```
SELECT patientId, detailId, `value`
FROM   patient_details AS pd
WHERE  detailId=(
           SELECT MAX(pd2.detailId)
             FROM patient_details AS pd2
             WHERE pd.patientId = pd2.patientId
               AND pd2.detailId IN (75, 151, 203) -- the added restriction
       )
;
```

Performance-wise, this involves a full table scan for the outer query; applying [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to the query for the sample schema & data gives the following [plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | pd | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 17 | 100 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pd2 | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 4 | pd.patientId | 4 | 30 | Using where; Using index |

Note the primary query joins 100% of the 17 rows to the dependent subquery.

#### Optimization

The uncorrelated subquery below will suggest an optimization: restricting the range of `detailId`. Applying the optimization to the correlated subquery gives:

```
SELECT patientId, detailId, `value`
FROM   patient_details AS pd
WHERE  detailId=(
           SELECT MAX(pd2.detailId)
              FROM patient_details AS pd2
              WHERE pd.patientId = pd2.patientId
                AND pd2.detailId IN (75, 151, 203)
                AND pd2.detailId BETWEEN 75 AND 203 -- optimization
       ) AND pd.detailId BETWEEN 75 AND 203 -- optimization
;
```

This cuts the number of rows from the primary query that get joined by 9:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | pd | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 17 | 11.11 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pd2 | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 4 | so.pd.patientId | 4 | 5.88 | Using where; Using index |

The optimization similarly effects row filtering in the dependent subquery, but that ultimately won't affect performance as these rows aren't joined to anything following.

### Uncorrelated Subquery

The uncorrelated subquery is also easily adapted in the same way: change the names and add the condition to the subquery:

```
SELECT pd.patientId, pd.detailId, pd.`value`
  FROM patient_details AS pd
    JOIN (
        SELECT patientId, MAX(detailId) AS detailId
          FROM patient_details
          WHERE detailId IN (75, 151, 203) -- the added restriction
          GROUP BY patientId
      ) AS pd2
      ON pd.patientId = pd2.patientId AND pd.detailId = pd2.detailId
;
```

However, performance is a little worse than the basic correlated subquery:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5 | 100 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | pd | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 8 | pd2.patientId,pd2.detailId | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 2 | DERIVED | patient_details | NULL | index | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | details_of_patient | 8 | NULL | 17 | 30 | Using where; Using index |

#### Optimization

The poor performance is largely because of the `IN` condition. The plan for the unrestricted query is much more performant:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5 | 100 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | pd | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 8 | pd2.patientId,pd2.detailId | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 2 | DERIVED | patient_details | NULL | range | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 4 | NULL | 5 | 100 | Using index for group-by |

Note that according to this plan, the query uses a [range](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#jointype_range) join on `pd2`, as opposed to the [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#jointype_index) scan shown in the plan for the restricted query. This points to a possible optimization: add a range condition on `detailId`:

```
SELECT pd.patientId, pd.detailId, pd.`value`
  FROM patient_details AS pd
    JOIN (
        SELECT patientId, MAX(detailId) AS detailId
          FROM patient_details
          WHERE detailId IN (75, 151, 203)
            AND detailId BETWEEN 75 AND 203 -- the added optimization
          GROUP BY patientId
      ) AS pd2
      ON pd.patientId = pd2.patientId AND pd.detailId = pd2.detailId
;
```

This results in a better plan than the unoptimized query (though still trailing the optimized queries), as it reduces the number of rows in the primary select:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 | 100 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | pd | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 8 | pd2.patientId,pd2.detailId | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 2 | DERIVED | patient_details | NULL | index | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | details_of_patient | 8 | NULL | 17 | 5.88 | Using where; Using index |

As of MySQL 8.0, the query can be written with a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html):

```
WITH pd2 AS (
    SELECT patientId, MAX(detailId) AS detailId
      FROM patient_details
      WHERE detailId IN (75, 151, 203)
        AND detailId BETWEEN 75 AND 203
      GROUP BY patientId)
SELECT pd.patientId, pd.detailId, pd.`value`
  FROM patient_details AS pd
    JOIN pd2
      ON pd.patientId = pd2.patientId AND pd.detailId = pd2.detailId
;
```

### LEFT JOIN

The left join is the trickiest to adapt, as naively adding the `detailID` restriction will produce incorrect results most of the time. Starting from the documentation example (after renaming):

```
SELECT pd.patientId, pd.detailId, pd.`value`
  FROM patient_details AS pd
    LEFT JOIN patient_details AS pd2
      ON     pd.patientId = pd2.patientId
         AND pd.detailId < pd2.detailId
  WHERE pd2.patientId IS NULL
;
```

Adding conditions to the `WHERE` clause will fail in two different ways:

1. The `JOIN` happens before the `WHERE`; by the time the latter clause is evaluated, the desired rows are likely already excluded.
2. `pd2.detailId` will be NULL for the groupwise-maximum rows, so testing it will always fail for exactly the desired rows.

The filtering must happen before the `JOIN` which means it must be done in subqueries replacing the simple table references:

```
SELECT pd.patientId, pd.detailId, pd.`value`
  FROM (SELECT * FROM patient_details WHERE detailId IN (75, 151, 203)) AS pd
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM patient_details WHERE detailId IN (75, 151, 203)) AS pd2
      ON     pd.patientId = pd2.patientId
         AND pd.detailId < pd2.detailId
  WHERE pd2.patientId IS NULL
;
```

Note the subquery is repeated. For MySQL 8.0 and higher, the query can be written using a CTE, which is [DRYer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (and thus more robust):

```
WITH pd AS (SELECT * FROM patient_details WHERE detailId IN (75, 151, 203))
SELECT pd.patientId, pd.detailId, pd.`value`
  FROM pd
    LEFT JOIN pd AS pd2
      ON     pd.patientId = pd2.patientId
         AND pd.detailId < pd2.detailId
  WHERE pd2.patientId IS NULL
;
```

The quantities in the estimated performance is similar to the correlated subquery:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | patient_details | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 17 | 30 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | patient_details | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 4 | patient_details.patientId | 4 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

However, this does a better job filtering the rows early, resulting in only 30% of 17 rows, or about 5 rows, of `pd` getting joined to `pd2`.

#### Optimization

The optimization for the uncorrelated subquery can be applied to this query:

```
WITH pd AS (
    SELECT * 
      FROM patient_details 
      WHERE detailId IN (75, 151, 203)
        AND detailId BETWEEN 75 AND 203
  )
SELECT pd.patientId, pd.detailId, pd.`value`
  FROM pd
    LEFT JOIN pd AS pd2
      ON     pd.patientId = pd2.patientId
         AND pd.detailId < pd2.detailId
  WHERE pd2.patientId IS NULL
;
```

This does an even better job in filtering out rows before the join:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | patient_details | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 17 | 5.88 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | patient_details | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 4 | so.patient_details.patientId | 4 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

Note an estimated 5.88% of the 17 rows from `pd` will get joined to `pd2`, one of the best performances of all the options.

### CTE with Window Function

The last example from the MySQL documentation uses a window function, [`Rank`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank), to assign a position to each row and filter based on that position. As with the subquery approaches, this query is easily adapted by the simple inclusion of the condition, but only works starting with MySQL 8.0 (as that's the first version to support window functions). After the usual rename and restriction addition:

```
WITH pd AS (
   SELECT patientId, detailId, `value`,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY patientId
                           ORDER BY detailId DESC
                      ) AS `Rank`
     FROM patient_details
     WHERE detailId IN (75, 151, 203)
)
SELECT patientId, detailId, `value`
  FROM pd
  WHERE `Rank` = 1
;
```

Note this is basically the query in SOS's answer, only using `Rank` rather than [`Row_Number`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number). Performance is quite good, comparatively:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  |  | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 8 | const | 1 | 100.00 |  |
| 2 | DERIVED | patient_details |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 17 | 30 | Using where; Using filesort |

Optimizations won't improve matters, as the primary select cannot be further optimized. Adding the usual optimization results in more rows being filtered out of the derived selection, but (as noted with the optimized correlated subquery) this won't impact performance, since the derived selection isn't then joined to anything else.

### LIMIT

Consider Paul T's solution:

```
SELECT patientId, value
  FROM patient_details
  WHERE detailID IN (75, 151, 203)
    AND patientId = 123456
  ORDER BY detailID DESC
  LIMIT 1;
```

This has great performance for a single ID, scanning only 3 rows:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | patient_details | NULL | range | PRIMARY,details_of_patient | PRIMARY | 8 | NULL | 3 | 100 | Using where |

Applying the range restriction on `detailId` optimization to this query does not improve performance.

Note this query only returns the results for a single patient ID. To get the results for multiple patients, the query would need to be run separately for each, resulting in performance comparable to the unoptimized correlated subquery (though with more round-trips to the DB).